# Monad instance for EvalOption[A] in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats, applicative, flatmap

Imagine an `EvalOption` type defined as follows:

```scala
type EvalOption = [A] =>> Eval[Option[A]]
```

Is it possible to create an instance of Monad in such a way that the stack safety of Eval is maintained?

I was able to create an Applicative instance for such type, but I'm having problems implementing the `flatMap` method. So, if anyone knows  way of doing this I would be very grateful .

Thanks, have a nice one!

Comment: That would just be `OptionT` wouldn't it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Indeed! That's what I had in mind, but I wanted to see how it could be implemented without using monad transformers. However, if I can't find a way to implement it, I will definitely use your solution, thank you very much!

Comment: Well you can check how `OptionT` works, you basically have to `flatMap` and then `match`